# How to check wallet for balance?

Tags: php, html, server, rpc, bitcoin

I am having trouble because I have a website in PHP and I am using a library to communicate with my bitcoin server node over the RPC.

Everything is good and bitcoin can communicate with the website. I am generating new wallet using the command

```shell
getnewaddress "label"
```

The bitcoin then returns the new bitcoin address with label what I sent over the RPC and that works really good and very well. The thing is that I must check that wallet next 15 minutes and after 15 minutes if user submit the form with button "paid" I must once again check for balance of the wallet, if the wallet has the right balance server will send him the product over email.

In the past I know we could use watch wallet but as that has been deleted from the RPC I am having trouble with checking that wallet, also what would be the best approach of the checking something with PHP in x time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you regularly run bitcoin RCP command `listsinceblock`. Keep track of the last block you checked in a database or cache, and run this command in your preferred interval (example: 15 minutes). This will return all new transactions since the last time you ran the command.

If there are transactions, the destination wallet address will be included in the commands response.

Wiki explains the command pretty well:

**listsinceblock  [blockhash] [target-confirmations]**

```
Get all transactions in blocks since block [blockhash], or all transactions if omitted. [target-confirmations] intentionally does not affect the list of returned transactions, but only affects the returned "lastblock" value.
```

[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)